Best betting strategy with positive EV while avoiding large loss
Coming from a financial stop loss background. Let's say in a game of $T$ rounds:

You start with $X_0=100$. And your profit $P=0$.
At round $t$, you can choose the bet size $z_t$. You will get $z_t\cdot \left(1+\epsilon_t)\right)$ back, ie $r_t=z_t\cdot \epsilon_t$ is your profit/loss this round, where $\epsilon_t$ follows iid $N(1,100)$. So on average you should be profitable but it comes with a risk.
At end of each round, first calculate your current capital $\tilde{X_t} = X_{t-1}+r_t$. Then if $\tilde{X_t}\geq X_0$, set $X_t=X_0$ and $P_t = P_{t-1} + (\tilde{X_t}-X_0)$. If $\tilde{X_t}< X_0$, set $X_t = \tilde{X_t}$. That is, if you are in profit, you bank the profit and restart. If you are in loss, you accumulate the loss.
At the end of $T=256$ rounds, set $P_T$ = $P_{T-1} + (X_T-X_0)$.

You want to maximise $P_T$, but with the constraint that all $X_i\geq 0.85\cdot X_0$, ie at any time, your cumulative loss cannot exceed 15%. What is the best betting strategy $z_t$, which I assume should be a function of $X_{t-1}$ but nothing else.
Not looking for a complete answer, any hint or point of paper/direction would be great.
PS: The problem above is probably not very rigorously defined. I guess rigorously we are $$\max_{z_t}E[P_T\cdot \Pi_{i=1}^T \mathrm{Indicator}(X_i\geq0.85X_0)]$$.
